# Поиск файла относительно пути сайта

Tags: php

```
function logdata($str) {
    $file = 'logs/'.date("Y-m-d").
    '.log';
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        $fp = fopen($file, "w");
        fwrite($fp, $ip);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

> Php файл расположен по пути название_сайта/Auth и ищет файл относительно этого пути - подскажите как указать поиск из основной папки сайта : название_сайта/logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'logs/'.date("Y-m-d") . '.log';
```